# GPG gives invalid packet (ctb=0a) error when trying to import public keys

Tags: linux, apt, ubuntu-20.10, keyserver

Trying to update gives me an error saying public keys are not available:
[image]

So I tried to import the keys using apt-key, which raises this invalid packet error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to fix this myself.

**Issue:**

gpg keyring is damaged

**Soulution:**

1. Delete **/etc/apt/trusted.gpg** and all .gpg files in **/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/**
2. Download [launchpad-getkeys](https://github.com/sa1/launchpad-getkeys) binary and execute it as sudo

Comment: Got the same problem on a Raspbian and this was the only solution I found that mentioned the invalid packets. Thanks for sharing it, I hope it can help others, too.